# callback url for real time updates from facebook-graph-api for a client application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-7

I need to get the real time updates from the facebook graph api for a windows 8 metro style application using javascipt & HTML5. Since the application is a client application ,it does not have any callback url. Can someone please tell me how this is done in case of windows 7 mobile phone applications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [real time updates from facebook graph api](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11141333/real-time-updates-from-facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 1):

The Real-time Updates can only be used if you have a server to handle the update request from facebook.
This feature is not intended for client-side only applications.